# Как обращаться к переменным внутри конструктора с использованием шаблона с большим количеством аргументов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20

есть такой шаблон

```
struct constr {
    template <typename F, typename ... Args>
    constr(F&& cond, Args&& ... args) {


    }
}
```

Я к нему обращаюсь например так

```
constr(variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4);
```

например использовать **variable1** я могу внутри шаблона через **cond**

```
struct constr {
    template <typename F, typename ... Args>
    constr(F&& cond, Args&& ... args) {

       std::cout << cond << std::endl;

    }
}
```

а как мне использовать остальные переменные которые внутри **args** по одному, отдельно не по очереди?

Comment: Проще всего сложить в tuple, а потом сделать get. Наиболее канонично так: `std::get<номер>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`. Еще можно сложить в массив - это позволит выбирать индекс во время выполнения, но требует, чтобы все типы приводились к какому-то одному: `int arr[] = {std::forward<Args>(args)...};`.

Comment: Но вообще, вам точно нужен отдельный элемент? Не цикл по элементам?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да мне именно отдельный нужен элемент и все они буду разного типа.

Comment: Ну значит первый вариант. Учтите, что он может выдать rvalue (через который вы можете переместить элемент), поэтому если нужно читать конкретный элемент больше одного раза, то чтение без перемещения пишется как-то так: `std::get<номер>(std::tie(args...))`.