# Как получить доступ к аргументам внутри структуры?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне нужно получить аргументы внутри конструктора.
Можно ли записать их в массив и потом с ними работать?

```
struct prototype {
    template <class... T1>
    prototype(T1 ...args) {
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
        // Это так не работает
        std::cout << "args[0]" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "args[1]" << std::endl;
        // Где они хранятся, не могу понять?
    }
};

int option_1 = 10;
std::string option_2 = "test2";
std::vector<int> option_3(10);
auto option_4 = 0.41;


int main() {

    prototype(option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4);
    prototype(option_1, option_2);
    
    system("pause");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Чем это отличается от https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1412611/215103 ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ничем, особо, тот же вопрос, просто там не отвечают, может не так спросил.
Я понять не могу, толи вопрос тупой, толи другая проблема

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Здесь все-таки вопрос задан более конкретно; я бы скорее первый закрыл как дубль второго :)... но не успел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, например, так устроит?...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

struct prototype
{
    vector<any> p;
    template <class... T1>
    prototype(T1 ...args)
    {
        (p.push_back(args), ...);
        std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
    }


};

int option_1 = 10;
std::string option_2 = "test2";
std::vector<int> option_3(10);
auto option_4 = 0.41;


int main() {

    prototype p1(option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4);
    prototype p2(option_1, option_2);

    cout << any_cast<double>(p1.p[3]) << endl;
    cout << any_cast<string>(p2.p[1]) << endl;
}
```

Или как вариант:

```
struct prototype
{
    template <class... T1>
    prototype(T1 ...args)
    {
        auto p = forward_as_tuple(args...);
        cout << get<0>(p) << endl;
        if constexpr(tuple_size_v<decltype(p)> >= 3 )
        {
            cout << get<3>(p) << endl;
        }
    }


};

int option_1 = 10;
std::string option_2 = "test2";
std::vector<int> option_3(10);
auto option_4 = 0.41;


int main() {

    prototype p1(option_1, option_2, option_3, option_4);
    prototype p2(option_1, option_2);

}
```

Да, к вашему

> Где они хранятся, не могу понять?

Пока не сохраните сами — нигде, потому что все эти разборки выполняются *во время компиляции*, а не во время выполнения.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136523/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-------).